Custom biblatex style (looks like natbib)
I would like to create a personalized biblatex style with the following properties:

Support for \cite{} with the output Author (year)
Support for \citeauthor{} with the same output as \cite{} minus the year, e.g. just Author
Both citation commands should be clicklable/colorable, i.e. for \cite{} there should be a single color and single link for both parts of the citation.
If there are 2 or 3 authors all should be shown. If there are 4 or more it should show  the first author and et al.
The reference list should include all authors, full first+last name and sorted by last name
The format should be: First, Last. Title. In Journal, ... , year where ... is the rest of the publication info and year should be last.

After a lot of searching, I (think that) have managed to hack around bit by bit to create everything except that I cannot move the date in the end of the reference entry. I have found a relative question but just adding in the code does not work for me.
I present the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\input{bibmod}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{1, 1b, 2, 3, 5}

\citeauthor{1, 1b, 2, 3, 5}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

The file with the modifications:
\usepackage[maxcitenames=3,
            mincitenames=1,
            maxbibnames=99,
            style=authoryear,
            natbib=true,
            language=british,
            uniquelist=false]
            {biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
\boolfalse{pagetracker}%
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\indexnames{labelname}%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%removes comma
\DeclareDelimFormat[cite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

%shows first name first
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}

%remove quotes from titles
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1.}

%remove : from In
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\printtext{In}\addspace}

%remove parentheses around year
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 

And a toy bib file
@article{1,
  title={Single author},
  author={Zuthor, Aa},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2024}
}
@article{1b,
  title={Single author again},
  author={Zuthor, Aa},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2024}
}

@article{2,
  title={Two authors},
  author={Author, Aaa and Buthor, Bbb},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2024}
}
@article{3,
  title={Three authors},
  author={Author, Aaa and Buthor, Bbb and Cuthor, Ccc},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2024}
}
@article{5,
  title={Five authors},
  author={Author, Aaa and Buthor, Bbb and Cuthor, Ccc and Duthor, Ddd and Euthor, Eee},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2024}
}

Is it possible to move the date without breaking anything else?
UPDATE
After some search, I found out that I can use the option mergedate=false. As a result I have two dates now, i.e.
Author (2024), Title, In Journal (2024) and I have to modify the second and suppress the first. Any ideas?

Is this an institutional requirement? Because it doesn't make sense, imho, since the year is part of the entry's label. So splitting it off from the author and sticking it at the end is just making it harder for readers to find the entry they want.

@cfr Yes, the last 2 properties are not my picks.

The trouble is the splitting up of what Biblatex regards as the label?

@cfr Yes that is the problem. I even found a relevant question (see the linked one in my post) but I cannot piece it together with the rest of my changes.
